# How to solve FPDF error: File is encrypted?

Tags: fpdf

My FPDF was working nicely but suddenly it is making problem to generate pdf file.
Now when i am going to generate pdf it is showing an error
"FPDF error: File is encrypted!"

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

I have already tried with like this:
ini_set("pcre.backtrack_limit", "1000000000");
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

Comment: can you show us your code? and did you change anything?

Comment: Thanks @Lithilion for commenting, I have found the cause of the problem, the library was not capable to take encrypted pdf, my uploaded pdf was encrypted, for this reason the problem was occurring.

Comment: @NazmulHasanNero Which library are you using now? I have the same problem :)